# How to use volley in android to extract specific json?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

If my request returns a JSON object like this

```
{"autocomplete":["abc", "asd"]}
```

How can I get the array in the JSON and turn it into java ArrayList?

I find some methods like getString, getInt. But I don't find a method that could get the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
     val response = JSONObject(yourresponse)
 val Jarray: JSONArray = response.getJSONArray("autocomplete")
 for (i in 0 until Jarray.length()) {
        val jsonobject: JSONObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i)
        Log.e("TAG",jsonobject.toString())
       
    }
```

In this way you can do

Answer (score 0):

```
String response = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray array= c.getJSONArray("autocomplete");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
     JSONObject a = carteVisite.getJSONObject(j);
     Log.d("TAG", a);
}
```